# CakePHP rest API not working

Tags: php, cakephp, rest

I've a model "Note" whose controller looks like this- http://pastebin.com/TqVJm7Uw

When I send GET request `http://hostname/notes.json` I am able to see the notes in json format.
For example- http://pastebin.com/Haf6fq9S

But when I send GET request `http://hostname/notes/4febea9d928488a443000000.json` I get message-

```
{"code":"404","url":"\/notes\/4febea9d928488a443000000.json","name":"Action NotesController::4febea9d928488a443000000() could not be found."}
```

My route.php file looks like this-

```
CakePlugin::routes();
Router::parseExtensions();
Router::parseExtensions('json');
Router::mapResources('notes');/**
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

What could be wrong here? Why is REST requst for index working fine but not for view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using MongoDB datasource with CakePHP, the moment I switched back to good old MySQL driver, it started working just fine. Not sure what was wrong with MongoDB datasource.

Comment: REST routing accepts by default integer or uuid ids as passed parameter. You can change this by passing option to Router::mapResources('Notes', array('id' => 'regexhere'))